# How do I set the MSI exit-code to 0 if product is already installed using WiX?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, exit-code

I already have the following line in my WiX setup to check if the current version is already installed:

`<UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect='yes' Property='NEWPRODUCTFOUND'  Minimum='$(var.ProductVersion)' IncludeMinimum='no' />`

The MSI exits with a message and exit code "1638". 
However, this MSI is part of a bootstrapper that chains multiple MSIs together - and I want the bootstrapper to continue and install the following MSIs.

How do I tell WiX/MSI to exit with exit code 0 and no message dialog?

I could modify the bootstrapper but would rather prefer to set the exit code to 0.

(The exact exit code is: ERROR_PRODUCT_VERSION - "Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [WixExitEarlyWithSuccess Custom Action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixexitearlywithsuccess.htm) is what you need.

Comment: First your suggestion did not work - the problem was that if the exact same version is already installed the msi was using the cached installer - changes I made in WiX were just ignored. But after deinstalling and installing the patched version it worked. Thank you!